# MacBook Pro in sleeping regime

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

Will there be any damage to a MacBook Pro if I keep it in sleeping regime all the time?

The reason I don't switch it off is I had problems with the start button. It stopped working within a year and under guarantee they changed hardware but no one said to me how to exploit it properly or gave recommendations. (It turned out start button is linked to hardware and it's very weak and should not be pressed frequently but instead Macbook must be in sleeping mode to avoid pressing start button often).

In one year the same problem happened. As changing hardware is expensive they offered me to reformat it and all my applications were erased and it seems now it's running software for Macintosh.

What can I do to prevent any troubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing I can see where sleeping damages hardware as long as you keep the battery charged at 50% for long term storage.

It's a lot of work and you'll be connecting and disconnecting the charger more than if you powered the hardware off, but that's the only damage you could accelerate by keeping the battery always 100% full.

Software corruption and memory corruption might necessitate a reboot from time to time, but that's more about the software that you run than if you let the Mac sleep or not. Sleeping reduces software cycles, so you'll take longer to run into memory leaks or issues than if you just let the Mac run.

I think you have a good plan and can stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the sleep mode 99% of the time.  The only time I ever shut down is when there is a software update that requires it.  Or once  a month or so, I see my machine getting "confused" and a restart seems to resolve the issue.  (I usually just restart and then continue, using sleep when done for the time being.)